# R's equivalent to pythons String[3:] - How to get string char 3 to Infinity

Tags: r, regex, string

I am new to R and can't find an answer anywhere for splitting a string after the n'th char to infinity. I feel like this should be really simple. I tried gsub and gprep without success (R regex is weird!). In python this would be as simple as string[2:]. Any ideas?

In general, I am trying to create a new column in a melted frame which contains the digit from the variable name bp1, bp2, .. bp21, so I can perform a regression for each group across all bin performances and then apply the regression slope as a new variable.

```
dat %>% 
  select(Mod, MS, SDC_name, Type, Mod_Type, bp1:bp21) %>% 
  melt(id.vars = c("Mod", "MS", "SDC_name", "Type", "Mod_Type")) %>% 
  filter(variable %in% bp) %>% 
  group_by(SDC_name) %>% 
  mutate(bin = as.numeric(variable[[3:]])) %>% View()
```

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Comment: `substr(variable, 3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string is "mynameisjohn," and you want everything from the third character to the end:

```
x <- "mynameisjohn"
substr(x,3,nchar(x))
```

returns

```
[1] "nameisjohn"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `substring`: http://rfunction.com/archives/1692